# WP8.1 ISETOOL.exe - connect running emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to browse files of my game (windows phone 8.1), but have problems with it. I tried to do it with ISETOOL.exe, but it always starting another emulator. Even with deviceindex option. WP Power Tools program also can not connect to running emulator. How can I browse files on running emulator, not starting another one?

Comment: Seems problem is in different languages/regions (?) of emulators. In VS2013 I run game on "Emulator 8.1 WVGA inch 512MB", but ISETOOL.exe provides list of devices like "Emulator 8.1 WVGA inch 512MB (RU)". Changing language of VS Emulator not helping me..

Answer (score 0):

OS language and language of Visual Studio must be the same. I changed language of VS and it's work.